# angularjs $uimodal needs to be updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have a peculiar scenario, where my data gets updated even after a modal window is open. i am supposed to refresh the data on the modal pop-up by adding a new item on the modal popup.
Here is the plunker, i tried to pass `$rootScope`, but from documentation, realized that default scope passed is `$rootScope`.
My plunker link is 
https://plnkr.co/edit/hnMGHfsxPfq8BRCtVxqJ

I'm using angular ui bootstrap and using `$uibModal`
Please suggest a solution i can try.
In my plunker code, even if the $item is updated, my modal isnt being refreshed.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl as $ctrl" class="modal-demo">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">
                    <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); $ctrl.selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            Selected: <b>{{ $ctrl.selected.item }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="stackedModal.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title-{{name}}">The {{name}} modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body-{{name}}">
            Having multiple modals open at once is probably bad UX but it's technically possible.
        </div>
    </script>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$ctrl.open()">Open me!</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$ctrl.additems()">Add Item</button>
  {{ $ctrl.items}}
  <div class="modal-parent">
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($uibModal, $log, $document) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $ctrl.animationsEnabled = true;
  $ctrl.additems = function (){
    $ctrl.items.push("item"+($ctrl.items.length+1));

  };
  $ctrl.open = function (size, parentSelector) {
    var parentElem = parentSelector ? 
      angular.element($document[0].querySelector('.modal-demo ' + parentSelector)) : undefined;
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      size: size,
      appendTo: parentElem,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $ctrl.items;
        }
      }
    });
    setTimeout(function () {

           $ctrl.items.push("item"+($ctrl.items.length+1));
        }, 1000);

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $ctrl.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };



  $ctrl.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $ctrl.animationsEnabled = !$ctrl.animationsEnabled;
  };
});

// Please note that $uibModalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($uibModalInstance, items) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.items = items;
  $ctrl.selected = {
    item: $ctrl.items[0]
  };

  $ctrl.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close($ctrl.selected.item);
  };

  $ctrl.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

My issue specifically is here, the Modal is rendered already with items passed.
ctrl.items is updated after 1 second, but the modal window where items is passed is not updated. Is there a way i can send an update of **$ctrl.items** to modal window

```
setTimeout(function () {
                     $ctrl.items.push("item"+($ctrl.items.length+1));
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question itself along with a more detailed problem description. Demos are great but should only be used to support what actually exists in the question. People shouldn't have to go off site just t review the basics of your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was not very clear. From your plunkr I see that the modal data gets updated when the original data is modified. So, assuming that's your problem: Javascripts objects are copied by reference. So to avoid that you need to create a new copy of the object. Like so:

```
items: function () {
          return angular.copy($ctrl.items);
        }
```

Updated plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/pHDr0B0jWRBGeNSPu0t7?p=preview

Comment: i apologize, the real is the fact that, if i update the items on root, i want the items on the modal to be updated, but its not happening and trying to figure out a way to issue an update of items from the root.

Comment: It's happening. When you have the modal open, click some item and you will see the scope gets updated. You need force apply()

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out, the issue i was doing was , i sent items to my modal controller, but i map "items" collection into another object. so, even if i apply the changes my UI was not getting updated. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction